# Background execution, writing record to core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Is it possible for iOS app to add records to Core data while running on background? For example if detect a beacon, then add the location into core data?

Is there a example of how to implement this in swift?

Comment: yes it is possible, check the background execustion in ios library

Answer (score 0):

You can use `func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) { }` method in AppDelegate to write the code whatever you wish to execute when the app enters Background